# Can we always shift two disjoint convex bodies a little bit to decrease the volume of their convex hull?

Tags: convex-geometry

Let $K,L\subset\mathbb R^d$ be two ***disjoint*** compact convex sets with non-empty interiors. Can $x=0$ be a point of local minimum for the function $F(x)=\text{vol}_d(\text{conv(K,L+x))}$?

I was asked this question by Dan Florentin a few weeks ago and I still cannot answer it in high dimensions (for $d=1,2$ the answer is "No"). Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Intuitively, it seems that you should be able to move them closer together and thereby decrease volume, right? Do you have an example where moving them along the line connecting their centers closer doesn't do this?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins The intuition is exactly that, I agree. As for "centers", if you meant "move the centers of mass along the line connecting them" (the bodies are not necessarily symmetric), I honestly don't know though I thought a bit of this and a few other movement options, just couldn't come to any conclusions about them in high dimensions. If you meant just "take any two points in the bodies and move along the line connecting them", then yes, there are counterexamples.

Comment: Yes, I had meant the centroids --- the other kind of counterexamples seem easy to make. But now I'm not sure about the centroids idea, since perhaps there is a long narrow arm sticking out (but still convex); if the tip of the arm is far from the centroid, it might affect the move-centers-closer strategy.

Comment: Seems like you should move the bodies in the direction of the shortest line segment connecting the two bodies?

Comment: @DeaneYang Definitely not. You can draw two triangles on the plane as a counterexample to this idea. Notice also that the setup is affine invariant while your suggestion isn't, which already makes it a bit suspicious.

Comment: Oops. Thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: This reminds me a bit of the Kneser–Poulsen conjecture. Also if I have parsed correctly, the title of the question is the reverse of the question in the main text.

Comment: @TimothyChow "the title of the question is the reverse of the question in the main text" Literally yes, but the questions are equivalent up to the swap of "Yes" and "No" answers. I just didn't want to make the title too long or to use an awkward construct of the type "is it true that something cannot happen" instead of the straightforward "can it happen that" in the body. If you find it even mildly confusing, feel free to edit :-)

Comment: @fedja : It was mildly confusing when I first skimmed through and saw "For d=1,2 the answer is no" but I don't think it's worth editing.

Comment: What about the case when $K \cap L$ may be nonempty but has empty interior? This seems like a stronger statement because the obvious limiting argument to approach this case doesn't work. Do you know a counterexample there? I don't immediately see one.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This fails already for $d=3$.

Consider a tetrahedron, e.g. the convex hull of the points $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$. Let $K$ be the closed subset consisting of $\sum_{i=1}^4 a_i v_i$ with $\sum_{i=1}^4 a_i=1$ and $a_3 +a_4 \leq 1/2-\epsilon$. Let $L$ be defined similarly, but $a_1+a_2 \leq 1/2-\epsilon$. Clearly the convex hull of $K$ and $L$ is this tetrahedron.

Consider a shift vector $x$ which lowers the volume of the convex hull. By the convexity described in Alexandre's answer, we can assume $x$ is invariant under all symmetries of the situation. By the symmetry switching $v_1$ and $v_2$ and the one switching $v_3$ and $v_4$, $x$ is a multiple of $v_1+v_2-v_3-v_4$. It suffices to handle the case where it is a small positive multiple. (For a negative multiple, there would just be a local minimum further out.)

The chance in volume for small $x$ is the sum of, for each triangular face of the tetrahedron, the integral of the dot product of the surface normal of the face with any vector describing the change in the boundary of the polyhedron. The dot product of the surface normal of each face with $x$ is the same, up to sign. If we normalize so this is $1$, then this dot product will lie between $0$ and $1$ on the faces spanned by $v_1,v_2,v_3$ and $v_1,v_2,v_4$, and between $0$ and $-1$ on the spaces spanned by $v_1,v_3,v_4$ and $v_2,v_3,v_4$.

On the face $v_1,v_2,v_3$, this is the maximal convex function that is $0$ at $v_1$ and $v_2$, $1$ on $L$ (which are the points $av_1+bv_2+cv_3$ with $c \geq 1/2 +\epsilon$). In particular, with $c < 1/2+\epsilon$, its value is $c/(1/2+\epsilon)$. Clearly the integral depends continuously on $\epsilon$, so we will evaluate in the case $\epsilon=0$.  So the integral of this function divided by the area of the face is $$\frac{ \int_0^{1/2} (1-x) (2x)  dx + \int_{1/2}^1 (1-x)dx }{ \int_0^1 (1-x) dx} = \frac{  1/4 - 1/12  +1/2 - 3/8 }{1/2} = \frac{7}{12}$$

The same is true for the face $v_1,v_2,v_4$.

On the face $v_2,v_3,v_4$, this is the maximal concave function that is $-1$ on $v_3$ and $v_4$ and $0$ whenever $a \geq 1/2+\epsilon$, in other words when $a < 1/2+\epsilon$ it is $ -( (1/2+\epsilon)-a )/(1/2+\epsilon)$. Again there is a continuity and we can take $\epsilon=0$. Then the integral is

$$ - \frac{ \int_{0}^{1/2} (1-x) (1-2x) dx } { \int_0^{1} (1-x) dx} =+ \frac{1/2 -3/8 + 1/12}{1/2}= - \frac{5}{12}$$

Because $\frac{7}{12}-\frac{5}{12}>0$, the change in the $x$ direction is positive, and it remains so for $\epsilon$ sufficiently small.

---

I thought I would add some motivation for this answer after a friend asked me about it. Why this construction?

The first thing to notice when looking for a counterexample is that, for any disjoint compact convex bodies $K,L$, if we expand $K$ and $L$ to larger convex bodies $K',L'$ while keeping them within $\operatorname{conv}(K, L)$, then we haven $\operatorname{conv} (K',L') = \operatorname{conv} (K, L)$ so $$\operatorname{vol}_d ( \operatorname{conv} (K',L') )= \operatorname{vol}_d ( \operatorname{conv} (K, L)),$$ but $\operatorname{conv} (K',L'+x) \supseteq  \operatorname{conv} (K,L+x) $ so $$\operatorname{vol}_d ( \operatorname{conv} (K',L'+x) )= \operatorname{vol}_d ( \operatorname{conv} (K, L+x)).$$

Thus if $0$ was a local minimum before it is still a local minimum after, and growing $K$ and $L$ in that way might make it a minimum if it wasn't before. So if we're looking for an example we should certainly keep growing $K$ and $L$ until there is no room left. This is accomplished when  we separate the convex body $\operatorname{conv}(K,L)$ by a hyperplane, and let $K$ and $L$ each almost fill one of the two separated pieces.

So the question is a bit of a trick question: It's asking for two convex bodies, but you should really be looking for one convex body, cut in half (or, perhaps, divided unevenly).

Which convex body should you cut in half? Well, if convex body is a cylinder, so the two sides are identical, it will certainly not give an example as we can just push the two sides into each other on an equal axis. Even an approximate cylinder will not be an example for this reason. So we should make the two sides as different from each other as possible. In three dimensions, our best hope is to make one side tall and thin and the other side short and wide, which gives a tetrahedron.

Then it's a matter of calculating to see if the tetrahedron suffices.

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear to me why without loss of generality "$x$ is a multiple of $v_1+v_2-v_3-v_4$". I understand that, if $x$ lowers the volume, then its images under all appropriate symmetries will also do. But how does this imply that $x$ itself must be invariant with respect to the symmetries? I also don't understand how this invariance may be related to the convexity in any given direction.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Convexity in any direction implies convexity ( just think about the definition of convexity). Hence the average of $x$ over all the symmetries lowers the volume as well, but this average is invariant.

Comment: Thank you. Somehow, I did not think of $L+(x_0+ty)=(L+x_0)+ty$.

Comment: I agree that there is a counterexample here but am confused by the details of the computation. I computed the volume of the tetrahedron and the volume of the shape gotten by translating $K$ and $L$ until they touch, and the tetrahedron was smaller. Combined with convexity, this shows that the local minimum occurs at some distance where $K$ and $L$ are disjoint. However, you seem to be showing the the derivative of volume is negative when $K$ and $L$ are slid further apart. That can't be right. (continued)

Comment: Let $C$ be the region of the tetrahedron in neither $K$ nor $L$. This polytope has $8$ vertices and is combinatorially a cube. Let $C(x)$ be the convex hull of these $8$ vertices where $K$ and $L$ are slid further apart by $x$. Then the volume of the convex hull of $K$ and $L+x$ contains the disjoint sets $K$, $L$ and $C(x)$. As $x$ grows, $C(x)$ keeps the same rectabgular cross sections but gets taller, so $\mathrm{Volume}(C(x))$ increases and thus the convex hull of $K$, $L$ and $C(x)$ increases.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Did I do the signs wrong? I only tried to compute the derivative of volume as $K$ and $L$ are slid closer together. The volume will not be differentiable at this point because moving in either direction breaks the flatness of the faces and creates new vertices. You can see the same phenomenon in the convex hull of a line segment and a moving point - when the point is colinear with the line segment, the area is not differentiable.

Comment: Looks correct to me. Amazing! I would never think one should search for a counterexample, especially in as low dimension as 3. Thanks, Will!

Comment: Shouldn’t the two fractions be $\frac{1/4-1/12+1/2-\mathbf{3/8}}{1/2}$, resp. $\mathbf{-}\frac{1/2-3/8+1/12}{1/2}$?

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler Calculus is hard...

Comment: By the way, this is true for $0<\epsilon<1-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}$. For $\epsilon = 1-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}$ the volume of the convex hull remains exactly constant while moving $K$ and $L$ together.

Comment: @TimothyBudd Cool. Is this based on doing the same integral I did, but keeping track of $\epsilon$, or did you use a different method?

Comment: More like Mathematica-fu (might require v11): `volume[e_,x_]:=RegionMeasure@ConvexHullMesh@Flatten[{#,{x,0,0}-#[[{1,3,2}]]}& /@{{-1,1,0},{-1,-1,0},{-2e,1/2+e,1/2-e},{-2e,1/2+e,-1/2+e},{-2e,-1/2-e,1/2-e},{-2e,-1/2-e,-1/2+e}},1]`

Comment: @TimothyBudd If you have a free time, illustrating this question with your Mathematica code would be a nice addition to [Wolfram demonstrations project](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/) :)

Answer (score 10):

I think this may help:

Lemma. For any two convex sets, and any vector $x$, the function $F(t)={\mathrm{Vol}}\left(\mathrm{conv}\left(K\cup(L+xt)\right)\right)$
is convex, as a function of real variable $t$.

This is cited in https://math.bme.hu/~ghorvath/surveyonconvhullvolumebeamer1.pdf

with the reference to

Fary, I., Redei, L. Der zentralsymmetrische Kern und die
zentralsymmetrische Hulle von konvexen Korpern. Math. Annalen.
122 (1950), 205-220.

Comment: So a local minimum would have to be a global minimum. (If there is a local minimum which isn't global, look at the line joining it to the global minimum and you have a convex function on $\mathbb{R}$ with two local minima, contradiction.) This seems like good progress because it feels like the global minimum should involve $K \cap (L+x)$ being large, but I can't prove it.

Comment: There is a large literature on finding the minimum of $F(t)$ numerically, but  so far I found no general properties of this minimum.